# Shortest cycle for each vertex

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I have an unweighted undirected graph.How is it possible in this graph for each vertex to find the length of the shortest cycle containing it?

P.s
This graph have not non-tree edge, but it have a cycle. What can be considered subtrees of the vertical 10? How will the algorithm work when the BFS reaches 16 and 17? 
[image]

Comment: The picture is very small and hard to read. Anyway the graph is cyclic and therefore if you build a BFS tree (from any source vertex) there will be at least one non-tree edge.

Comment: When I start the BFS from the top 10, then if you look at two subtrees, then first it will go 15, 14, then 16, 17. And if I understand you correctly, then here it will find those (u,v). But edge (16,17) is non-tree edge?

Comment: $(16, 17)$ is a non-tree edge w.r.t. the BFS tree rooted at $10$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way is as follows: For each vertex $s$, perform a BFS visit to discover the shortest cycle containing $s$.

When a visit from $s$ is performed a BFS tree $T_s$ is built and each non-tree edge $(u,v) \not\in E(T)$ for which $u$ and $v$ belong to different subtrees rooted in the children of $s$ in $T$ tree induces a cycle containing $s$.
Since, the shortest cycle containing $s$ must use a non-tree edge $(u,v)$ with this property, it will be found by the visit. You can optionally stop the visit early: if you find a cycle while visiting $u$, you can stop the BFS as soon as all the vertices in the level of $T$ containing of $u$ are visited.

The overall required time is $O(n \cdot m)$.

Comment: But what if, for example, v and u belong to the same subtree andhave a non-tree edge?

Comment: Then the cycle formed by $(u,v)$ and the path in the BFS tree from $u$ to $v$ cannot contain $s$ and you don't need to worry about it. When you run the BFS on $s$ you are only interested in finding the shortest cycle containing $s$.